# Regular expression to allow characters, numbers, white space, and some special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

My regular expression is

```
var regxepr=/^[a-zA-z0-9&\/\\#.:_\\s\-]$/
```

But this regular expression is allowing strings that contains `[`, `]`, `^` and ` (back-tick).
Its not returning false for these characters and these characters are not present in the allowed special characters list.

Comment: @Tushar exactly....Let me find the link..

Comment: `var regex = /^[a-z\d&\/.:_\s-]+$/i`

Comment: The problem is `A-z` in the regex which covers the range `65-122` which involves special characters like `[`(91) and `]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj found it. Maybe you could find a better one